# Sed/Awk script to print fields based on first characters

Tags: awk, sed

I am new to sed and awk. As such, I am not to sure which one to use for this particular task (or even if it is correct to use). Here is what I want to do:

I have a file containing lines of data delimited by "|". It will look something like this:

```
ln1: |a=1|b=5|d=77|h=2222|
ln2: |c=9|b=21|g=0.00001|a=3|k="helloworld"|h=101|
.....
```

Now each line can have a different number of fields and fields may not occur in the same order.

I want to write a script to pull out fields based on the field's ID. So say I wanted fields starting with "a=" and "h=" and also "g=" (if "g=" field exists),  the script will print out

```
ln1:|a=1|h=2222|
ln2:|a=3|h=101|g=0.00001|
```

Thanks a lot folks!

Comment: are the lines starting with `ln1:` ?
also are they starting with `|` seperator?

Comment: What about grep? `grep -E "^\|[ahg]=" filename` ?

Comment: Lines do not start with `ln1:` and they do start with `|`, but I can easily change that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$ awk -F\| '{out=$1"|"; for ( i=0; i< NF; i++ ) out =out""($i ~ /^[ahg]/?$i"|":""); print out}' input
ln1: |a=1|h=2222|
ln2: |g=0.00001|a=3|h=101|
```

**OR**

A lengthy version if you want the output to be in order `a h g`

```
$ awk -F\| '
BEGIN{a[1]="a=[^|]+"; 
      a[2]="h=[^|]+"; 
      a[3]="g=[^|]+" } 

     {out=$1"|"; 
      for(i in a) {
          match($0,a[i] ,arr); 
          out=out""arr[0]"|"
       } 
     print out 
    }' input


ln1: |a=1|h=2222||
ln2: |a=3|h=101|g=0.00001|
```

Comment: I keep getting a syntax error around the second comma in the match function. Any idea why? I like how this prints an empty field in the output.

Comment: @AnPocArBuile I couldnt replecate the error. Which awk version are you using. Tested in `GNU Awk 3.1.5`

Comment: @AnPocArBuile   Am not sure about that. But it seems working on my system

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F\| -v ORS=\| '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(match($i,/ln|a=|h=|g=/)){print $i}}printf("\n")}' File
```

**Sample:**

```
AMD$ awk -F\| -v ORS=\| '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(match($i,/ln|a=|h=|g=/)){print $i}}printf("\n")}' File
ln1: |a=1|h=2222|
ln2: |g=0.00001|a=3|h=101|
```

Comment: You can change `-v ORS="|"` to `-v ORS=\|` to make it more equal the `-F\|`

Comment: or even better `BEGIN{FS=ORS="|"}` so you don't have to hard-code the same value twice. Similarly, `/ln|a=|h=|g=/` can be reduced to `/ln|[ahg]=/`.

Answer (score 1):

using only `awk`:

```
awk -vfields_to_write='a,h,g' -F'\|' '{
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i,arr,"="); d[arr[1]]=arr[2]; 
  }
  split(fields_to_write,fields,","); 
  str="";
  for (f in fields) 
      if (d[fields[f]]) 
          str=str"|"fields[f]"="d[fields[f]]; 
  print str"|"
 }'
```

The output will look like:

```
|a=1|h=2222|
|a=3|h=101|g=0.00001|
```

Comment: That `split()` will fail if any of his fields contains an `=` inside a string, for example if `k="helloworld"` was `k="hello=world"`, and the test on `d[fields[f]]` will fail if any of the fields had a value of null or numeric zero, e.g. `a=0`. Also the `in` operator will print the fields in the order they are stored in the hash table, not the order they are specified on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
# put all field ordered, multi instance if wanted as output wanted in place
# of ahg in line here after (ex: babh)
s/^/ahg-/;G
:cycle
s/^\([^-]\)\([^-]*\)-\([^:]*:\)\(.*\)\(|\1=[^|]*\)\(.*\)/\2-\3\4\6\5/
t cycle
s/^[^-]//
t cycle
s/-\([^:]*:\).*\n\(.*\)/\1\2|/
```

- a bit longer but not limited to ahg with very few modification
- assume there is always at least 1 field avaialble (no error management)

posix version (so `--posix`on GNU sed)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have an input file that contains `name=value` pairs, it's best to create an array containing that mapping and then you can just print the fields you want by their name. For example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{
    FS=" *[|] *"
    OFS="|"
    split(flds,fldsA,"")
}
{
    delete n2v          # or split("",n2v) if non-gawk
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        name = value = $i
        sub(/=.+/,"",name)
        sub(/[^=]+=/,"",value)
        n2v[name] = value
    }

    printf "%s", $1
    for (i=1; i in fldsA; i++) {
        name = fldsA[i]
        if (name in n2v) {
            value = n2v[name]
            printf "%s%s=%s", OFS, name, value
        }
    }
    print "|"
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v flds="ahg" -f tst.awk file
ln1:|a=1|h=2222|
ln2:|a=3|h=101|g=0.00001|
$
$ awk -v flds="db" -f tst.awk file
ln1:|d=77|b=5|
ln2:|b=21|
$
$ awk -v flds="hkba" -f tst.awk file
ln1:|h=2222|b=5|a=1|
ln2:|h=101|k="helloworld"|b=21|a=3|
$
```